# How android system autoconnects to paired device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

**What I want to know:**

I'm wondering how the android system (like Android smart phone) auto-connects to devices which is paired before.

*For example*, I pair my bluetooth headset with my android smartphone in the procedure of `"turn on scanning/advertising -> click pairing"` on day 1. And when I turn on advertising on my headset, it connects automatically on day 2, 3, 4, and so on. The point is, I don't have to make my smartphone scan again to find my (paired) headset.

I can't understand how android system finds that the paired device is turned on. Does the android system scan periodically in background? Even if I don't click "scan" button?

**Why I ask:**

I want to make my app autoconnect to customized BLE device, after make pairing. I succeed to make pairing(bonding) with `createBond()` method, but after that, I couldn't find how to make autoconnect. I know I can turn on autoconnect function like this way, `connectGatt(XXX, true, XXX)`, but this autoconnect function doesn't work when the BLE device is disconnected a few days.

So I want to make my app works like android system and Bluetooth headset. But I couldn't find how android bluetooth system works even I dig AOSP codes.

I found many questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460012/how-to-autoconnect-to-a-paired-device-ble-without-scanning) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717752/autoconnecting-to-known-ble-device)) about problems like mine but there were no answers.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

I found that `bt_btif` gets activated (with LG smartphone and Nexus 5) when the paired headset is turned on (start advertising). But `bt_btif` doesn't get activated with my custom BLE device... What can I do?

Comment: It's no use looking to your headset as an example: scanning works completely differently for classic Bluetooth vs. BLE.

Answer (score 2):

Executing `connectGatt(XXX, true, XXX)` is the correct way to go. `gatt.connect()` also starts an auto connect. Once you execute that, your phone will scan for the device and once it appears it connects to it. The only thing that interrupt this call is either if Bluetooth is turned off on the phone or if your app process is being killed. To avoid your process from being killed, let your app have a foreground service.

One gotcha however, there is a bug in Android which will sometimes make auto connect do a direct connect instead (and cancel after 30 seconds or so). See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69834. You need to use reflection to avoid this bug.

Comment: thanks for your comment about the autoconnect bug!, it has led me down a debugging route i never would have investigated. There is a full java workaround for the bug in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39269766/5414907

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution.

First, the solution for my question: Android smartphone seems to detect state changes of nearby bluetooth devices from the hardware sides. When the paired bluetooth headset starts to advertise, a callback in HAL (I think) is called.

So I made my app to `connectGatt` with `autoConnection=True` to the device that I want, by using MAC address, when the activity is started (in `onResume()` of `MainActivity`).

The connection would fail if my BLE peripheral device is not advertising. But the device auto-connects when it starts advertising, because the `autoConnection` parameter was set to true.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar app and i didn't have problem with that. As a last resort for your problem, i would suggest writing the BLE Device Address in a simple DB table and manually connect to it. I've made something like this [here](https://github.com/hstaykov/baggiie/blob/master/src/com/baggie/ble/BluetoothLeService.java)
. It is no best practice code, but i hope you can find ideas for you solution.

Comment: What I want to make is reconnecting to BLE device automatically, without any inputs from user. I think your app connects to the device by clicking a device. If my understanding is wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Correct for the initialization, but you can do a similar thing on other event, for example when the app starts, or when a new device is discovered, to check if its address i already in the DB.

Comment: I found a solution based on an idea inspired from your code. Thank you!